# Data is now not being inserted into database

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have a mysqli/php code below where it is suppose to insert data into the 'Session' Table. Now it used to insert data with no problems previously and I have not changed the code below:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')        
{        
    $time = str_replace(array(' Hrs ', ' Mins ', ' Secs'), 
               array(':', ':', ''), $_SESSION['durationChosen']);        
    for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; ++$i) 
    {               
            $insertsql = "
      INSERT INTO Session
        (SessionId, SessionTime, 
         SessionDate, SessionWeight, 
         SessionDuration, TotalMarks, 
         ModuleId, TeacherId, Room)
      VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }        
        $sessid = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
        $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

        $insert->bind_param("sssssssss", $sessid, 
          $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
          $_SESSION['textWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
          $_SESSION['module'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }        
        $insert->close();        
    } 
}
```

Like I said this code worked before and I have not changed anything in the code since. But I cannot remember if its because I change the table in the database (phpmyadmin) that it is not inserting data into the database.

Can anyone check the Table creation before and state if you see any problems? Could the problem be with other tables which contains SessionId as their foriegn key?

Below is the Table Creation using SHOW CREATE TABLE Session:

```
CREATE TABLE `Session` (
 `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `SessionTime` time NOT NULL,
 `SessionDate` date NOT NULL,
 `SessionWeight` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `SessionDuration` time NOT NULL,
 `TotalMarks` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `FileId` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ModuleId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `TeacherId` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `Room` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`SessionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: @rs I removed FileId from table column so there are 9 columns in table and 9 columns from php but still no data being inserted from mysqli/php

Comment: do you see any errors? can you print your sql on webpage and try to run that manually and test.

Comment: Do all the datatypes match?  Do you pass a value for all fields that are NOT NULL?  Is the primary key being inserted unique to the table?  Are you using/in the right database?  Do the number of columns in your insert statement match the number of fields you're trying to insert?  Could it be a privilige/permission issue with the DB?

Comment: Why are you binding all your variables as strings when there are several integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you are giving us, we have to make the following assumptions:

- Your logic flow is correct and we are making it inside the if and for loops
- The $_SESSION variable has all the keys you are claiming

With those assumptions the variable $teacherId is not being set, so it's value is null.  In your table create statement the TeacherID column does not accept a null value so the insert is failing.